# Need to click multiple times to get a cell value datagrid issue

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I am trying to click on cell to get its value. Some time it works, some times i have to click multiple times to get the value.
What's Wrong with my code?

```
 on Form Load

    SQL = Select Id, Cat_name From cat_tbl


 Private Sub dgcat_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgcat.CellContentClick
        If dgcat.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value IsNot Nothing Then
            ids = (dgcat.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString())
        End If
    End Sub
```

On Delete

```
SQL = Delete from cat_tbl where ID=ids
```

[image]

Comment: impossible to tell.. you're setting an `ids` var, presumably a member somewhere, but no code on where you're reading it back.

Comment: what type of DataGridViewColumn is that shown?

Comment: @porkchop ids column is hidden from user let me update another ss

Comment: i don't know what that is, but it isn't code ;o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the [DataGridView.CellContentClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which *triggers* only if your mouse cursor is placed **over** the content and **does not trigger** if your mouse cursor is over the cell but not **over the content**. Examples:

You **do not** have a hit because you are **not clicking the content**:

[image]

You have a hit because you are clicking **the content**:

[image]

That is why it looks like **sometimes works, sometimes not**. One solution would be to use the [DataGridView.CellClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the CellContentClick:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If (e.ColumnIndex <> -1) Then
        Dim value = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
        If (Not value Is Nothing) Then
            Dim ids = value.ToString()
            MessageBox.Show(ids)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This works always:

[image]

In your case the problem is very mean, because you are hitting sometimes exactly the area of couple of pixels that does not respond because it does not count as content:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lemon,
Please understand that cell content click is just that. Cell Content. Clicking only on the row will not provide you with the cells content, or value as you are looking for.

Please, notify that you are indeed clicking on the cell content.

In testing, I provided this code. If you do not receive the cells content when clicking on the cell's content, we may need to explore other options.

```
Dim ids As String
If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value IsNot Nothing Then
   ids = (DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString())
End If
MsgBox(ids)
```